# Looking for an author's anthology of short surreal/absurdist fiction (80s-90s)

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, anthology-book, authors

Summary: Anthology with short story about afterlife being a giant movie theater.

I am looking for a collection of short stories of a particular author. It was published in hardcover, and I picked up at a Barnes and Noble sometime in the late 80s or early 90s. The cover artwork was dark and shadowy with I believe red lettering.

The short stories principally of a surreal nature; some in the vein of absurdist dark humor, others bleak and bordering on horror. Unfortunately I only recall the plot line of one of the stories which for some reason I think was tied to this collection's title. The story implied that the character was in some sort of an afterlife which consisted of a gigantic movie theater where people needed to interpret an endless series of films and the main character makes an attempt to reach the projector room (God?).

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  There isn't a lot of detail here; you should check out the [suggestions for story id questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) to see if they help you remember any additional details.

Comment: Maybe one of these by j.G. Ballard? He wrote a lot of surreal, absurdist, and dark stories, but I haven't read them all.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Short_story_collections_by_J._G._Ballard

Comment: Anytime someone mentions surreal short fiction, my first thought is Philip K Dick.

Answer (score 4):

Any chance that story is the novella ["The Calvin Coolidge Home for Dead Comedians"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?49249) by Bradley Denton, republished in both his [collection of that name](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?258186) and his collection [*One Day Closer to Death*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?24975)? There's no quest for God in that story, but, quoting Wikipedia's summary,

> In the afterlife, Leonard finds himself confined to the
> Calvin Coolidge Home for Dead Comedians, an institution
> where comedians who were rude, offensive, obscene, and
> blasphemous are kept until they can learn to shed those
> elements of their personalities which would make them
> unfit for Heaven.

The inmates are forced, every night, to watch *It's a Wonderful Life*. We eventually learn (or figure out?) that "Leonard" is Lenny Bruce. Excellent story.

The stories in *One Day Closer to Death* are uniformly dark, or angry. Some might qualify as horror.

Answer (score -1):

Well, since others are answering with stories instead of anthologies, I will stop withholding the story that kept intruding on my thoughts - mainly because the good SF story is a tad disgusting.

It is ["Spectator Sport by John D. MacDonald.](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?40925)

It was also answered with some story details a few years ago [here.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/137606/story-where-the-hero-ends-up-having-his-eyelids-removed-and-being-hooked-up-to-s)

I searched to see if it were part of an anthology on afterlife as a theater, but it doesn't seem to be so.

Comment: If it doesn't involve a movie theatre, or the afterlife, I'm not uncertain how it answers the question. Could you explain?