# Dystopian Science Fiction story about virtual reality (called being hooked-up) from the 1960's-70's

Tags: story-identification, virtual-worlds

Trying to identify this story for an acquaintance. They read it in the late 1970's, they were not sure if it was a novel or part of an anthology. They think it was published sometime in the 1960's or 70's.

From what they told me it was about people working to be placed in these cubicles where they could live in virtual worlds. Virtual reality was called being "hooked-up." Those who could not afford to be hooked up could be working as janitors cleaning the cubicles. I believe people were moved from an original nice looking cubicle into dingy cubicles as they would never know once they were hooked-up.

They distinctly remember a conversation between characters where they were talking about the world and planes. Specifically how those in power were fooling the mass populace by making them think oh how far we have come with these snazzy new planes but the planes were actually still functioning on really old technology, nothing really new about them. And that it was really like that through out this world.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Time Traveler mistaken for senile, put in VR](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/139459/time-traveler-mistaken-for-senile-put-in-vr) or [Story where the hero ends up having his eyelids removed and being hooked up to some kind of virtual reality machine](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/137606/story-where-the-hero-ends-up-having-his-eyelids-removed-and-being-hooked-up-to-s?rq=1)

Answer (score 16):

It's a very short story, but this strongly reminds me of "[Spectator Sport](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?40925)" (1950) by John D. MacDonald.  It was reprinted in the 1960s several times in the Asimov/Conklin anthology [*Fifty Short Science Fiction Tales*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?403556).

The story is of a man from the 1950s who jumps 400 years into the future to find everything run down, except for the fancy vans belonging to World Senseways.  He is prematurely lobotomized, and as a consolation is granted a permanent Hookup.

You can read the story in its original publication in *Thrilling Wonder Stories* at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/Thrilling_Wonder_Stories_v35n03_1950-02/page/n79/mode/2up).

Comment: That was it, thank you so much.

Comment: @Shae If this is the correct answer you should mark the answer as correct by clicking on the checkmark on the left side under the voting arrows.  (It will help future searchers by showing that your question has been answered.)  And you're most welcome!